# Select newest records from table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have table cars:

```
Id int,
Model nvarchar(max),
DateOfProduction (datetime).
```

And data like:

```
1 BMW X5 1.1.2010
2 BMW X5 1.1.2009
3 BMW X3 1.1.2008
4 BMW X3 1.1.2007
5 BMW X7 1.1.2005
```

And I want to get newest car for each model:

```
1 BMW X5 1.1.2010
3 BMW X3 1.1.2008
5 BMW X7 1.1.2005
```

I can't cope with this:/

Could you help me ?

Comment: Logically speaking, how can ID be lesser for newer models of car?

Comment: Funny :) it's only example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your given table structure, following SQL returns what you need but you might consider changing your table structure into something like this

```
cars (carid, model)  
production (carid, DateOfProduction)
```

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   dbo.Cars c
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT Model
                DateOfProduction = MAX(DateOfProduction)
         FROM   dbo.cars
         GROUP BY
                Model
       ) dm ON dm.DateOfProduction = c.DateOfProduction
               AND dm.Model = c.Model
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(Id), Model, MAX(DateOfProduction) FROM Table
GROUP by Model
```

This will work for the data given.

However, it assumes that you want the oldest Id and the newest date for that model